# Using Enum as/with expressions?

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

Is it possible to use an enum with expressions to reflect on the enum values?  Consider this *hypothetical* routine:

```
public enum Fruit
{
  Apple,
  Pear
}

public void Foo(Fruit fruit)
{
  Foo<Fruit>(() => fruit);
}

public void Foo<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    //... example: work with Fruit.Pear and reflect on it
}
```

`Bar()` will give me information about the enum, but I want to work with the actual value.

Background: I've been adding some helper methods to return CustomAttribute information for types and wondered if a similar routine could be used for enums.

I'm fully aware you can work with the enum type to get the CustomAttributes that way.

**Update:**

I use a similar concept in MVC with helper extensions:

```
public class HtmlHelper<TModel> : System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>
{
    public void BeginLabelFor<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    }
}
```

In this example `name` would be the member name of the model.  I want to do a similar thing with enums, so name would be the enum 'member'.  Is this even possible?

**Updated example:**

```
public enum Fruit
{
  [Description("I am a pear")]
  Pear
}

public void ARoutine(Fruit fruit)
{
  GetEnumDescription(() => fruit); // returns "I am a pear"
}

public string GetEnumDescription<T>(/* what would this be in a form of expression? Expression<T>? */)
{
  MemberInfo memberInfo;
  // a routine to get the MemberInfo(?) 'Pear' from Fruit - is this even possible?

  if (memberInfo != null)
  {
    return memberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description;
  }

  return null; // not found or no description
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to make Foo call Bar? Why are you using expression trees here? What are you actually trying to achieve? Your question is very vague at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, a case of changing before posting.  I've updated it and also added an example with a routine used for Mvc where the name of the property is extracted for a label.

Comment: It's still not clear why you don't just call `ToString()` which will give you the name associated with the value.

Comment: I'm not interested in the enum name, I was wondering if you could use the same expression technique to retrieve the enum attribute.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097766/how-to-get-custom-attribute-values-for-enums) describes using reflection how to get a custom attribute for an enum value.  Considering this approach touches on MemberInfo - is it not possible to use an expression with an enum to get the MemberInfo of the value and get the attributes that way?

Comment: What do you mean by "the enum attribute"? You said "name would be the enum 'member'" - assuming you mean "Pear" or "Apple", that's exactly what you get from `ToString`. If that's not what you want, you really need to give a full example of how you intend to call `Foo(Fruit)` and what you'd expect the result to be.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://weblogs.asp.net/grantbarrington/archive/2009/01/19/enumhelper-getting-a-friendly-description-from-an-enum.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `Expression`s for this. All you need to know is that `enum`s have a field for each of their values. This means you can do something like:

```
public static string GetEnumDescription<T>(T enumValue) where T : struct, Enum
{
    FieldInfo field = typeof(T).GetField(enumValue.ToString());

    if (field != null)
    {
        var attribute = field.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>();

        if (attribute != null)
            return attribute.Description;
    }

    return null; // not found or no description
}
```

Comment: From C# 7.3 you can use `where T : Enum`